# Formula for the intersection of a sphere with regards to stereographic projection

Tags: general-topology, geometry, stereographic-projections

So I have this question for an assignment and am just completely lost.

Let $S^n$ be the unit sphere with centre at $0$ in the space $R^{n+1}$. Let $N=(0,...,0,1)$ in such a space. Define the stereographic projection $p:S^n\setminus\{N\} \rightarrow R^n = R^n \times \{0\} \subset R^{n+1}$.

For each x in the sphere, the point $p(x)$ is the intersection of the line and the point $x,$ with the hyperplane $x_{n+1} =0.$

I need to find an explicit formula for such $p(x)$ and also its inverse, and then prove $p$ is a homeomorphism. I genuinely have no clue where to start.

From wikipedia and some videos, I have found some equations for $R^3$ but the $n+1$ has me completely lost. How do I derive such an equation, both in $R^3$ and particularly for any $R^{n+1}$?

Comment: It would be good to include the formula you got for $\mathbb{R}^3$. I wouldn't think it would be much different than what is in my answer.

Comment: A hint on formatting: MathJax (invoked by `$`) is not just a way to make subscripts and superscripts; it is a way to format **entire equations** and other formulas, short ones as well as long ones. Doing the MathJax just to bits and pieces of some formulas gives a strange-looking result.

Answer (score 1):

**The Power of a Point**

[image]

The [Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) of the point $p$ with respect to the unit circle centered at $O$ is
$$
(p-x)\cdot(p-N)=|p|^2-1\tag1
$$
The [Pythagorean Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) says
$$
|p-N|^2=|p|^2+1\tag2
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
(x-N)\cdot(p-N)
&=\left((p-N)-(p-x)\right)\cdot(p-N)\\
&=|p-N|^2-(p-x)\cdot(p-N)\\
&=2\vphantom{N^2}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Since $x-N\parallel p-N$ we get
$$
p-N=\frac2{|x-N|^2}(x-N)\tag4
$$
and
$$
x-N=\frac2{|p-N|^2}(p-N)\tag5
$$
Equations $(4)$ and $(5)$ give formulas to compute $p$ given $x$ and vice-versa.

Comment: @ThunderHex: I have simplified the answer using the power of the point $p$. I added a link to the Wikipedia article on this, but I did not add a section on the power of a point with respect to a circle. I can do so if desired.

Answer (score 1):

The line $\mathcal L_x$ through $N$ and $x \in S^n \setminus \{N\}$ can be parameterized by
$$l_x(t) = N + t(x -N) .$$
The coordinate functions of $l_x$ are
$$l^i_x(t) = \begin{cases} tx_i & i = 1,\ldots,n \\ 1 + t(x_{n+1} -1)  & i = n+1 \end{cases}$$
$\mathcal L_x$ intersects $\mathbb R^n \times \{0\}$ in the point $p(x)$. Thus we have to determine $t_0$ such that $l^{n+1}_x(t_0) = 1 + t_0(x_{n+1}-1) = 0$. We get
$$t_0 = \dfrac{1}{1-x_{n+1}}$$
and therefore
$$p(x) = l_x(t_0) = \left(\dfrac{x_1}{1-x_{n+1}},\ldots,\dfrac{x_n}{1-x_{n+1}},0\right) .$$

The inverse of $p$ can be determined as follows. Given $u = (u_1,\ldots,u_n,0) \in \mathbb R^n \times \{0\}$, we want to find $x \in S^n$ such that $p(x) = u$, i.e.
$$(\dfrac{x_1}{1-x_{n+1}},\ldots,\dfrac{x_n}{1-x_{n+1}}) = (u_1,\ldots,u_n).$$
This implies
$$\lVert u \rVert^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2 = \dfrac{1}{(1-x_{n+1})^2}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 .$$
We require $x \in S^n$, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_i^2 = 1$. Therefore
$$\lVert u \rVert^2 = \dfrac{1}{(1-x_{n+1})^2}(1-x_{n+1}^2) =  \dfrac{1+x_{n+1}}{1-x_{n+1}}$$
which gives
$$x_{n+1} = \dfrac{\lVert u \rVert^2 -1}{\lVert u \rVert^2 +1} $$
and
$$x_i = \dfrac{2u_i}{\lVert u \rVert^2 +1}, i =1, \ldots, n. $$
Thus
$$p^{-1}(u) = \left(\dfrac{2u_1}{\lVert u \rVert^2 +1}, \ldots, \dfrac{2u_n}{\lVert u \rVert^2 +1},\dfrac{\lVert u \rVert^2 -1}{\lVert u \rVert^2 +1}\right) .$$
This approach was purely formal. Alternatively we can do it geometrically. The line $\mathcal L_x$ through $N$ and $x$ is also a line through $N$ and $u = p(x)$ which can be parameterized by
$$g_x(t) = N + t(u -N) .$$
The coordinate functions of $g_x$ are
$$g^i_x(t) = \begin{cases} tu_i & i = 1,\ldots,n \\ 1 + t(u_{n+1} -1) = 1 -t  & i = n+1 \end{cases}$$
It is clear that $\mathcal L_x$ intersects $S^n$ in the two points $N$ and $x$. Thus we have to determine $t$ such that
$$1 = \lVert g_x(t) \rVert^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n t^2u_i^2 + (1-t)^2 =t^2\lVert u \rVert^2 + (1-t)^2. $$
This can be simplified to
$$0 = ((\lVert u \rVert^2 +1)t -2 )t .$$
Solutions are $t_0=0$ (which gives $g_x(0) = N$) and
$$t_1 = \dfrac{2}{\lVert u \rVert^2 + 1} .$$
We obtain
$$x = g_x(t_1) = \left(\dfrac{2u_1}{\lVert u \rVert^2 +1}, \ldots, \dfrac{2u_n}{\lVert u \rVert^2 +1},\dfrac{\lVert u \rVert^2 -1}{\lVert u \rVert^2 +1}\right) .$$

Comment: I think that parameterisation is screwing me over. From a pdf book I found, I have done the following:
Consider x (the point on the sphere) as {$a_1, a_2,...,a_n, γ$} 
Then consider p (the point where the line intersects the hyperplane) as p={$b_1, b_2,...,b_n,γ$} --> γ=0 at the hyperplane

Now consider a scalar η. We can say the line extending from N to p is a scalar multiple of the line from N to x. So we can then say η$a_n$ = $b_n$

Not sure what to do after this. For reference here is the pdf:
https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/leeriemm.pdf

Line 3.6, the second equation.

Comment: (following on) The second equation makes absolutely no sense to me. With your parameterisation, when t is 1, then what exactly does tx represent? I'm not sure how to phrase it, but would you be able to explain the parameterisation?

Comment: If $a, b$ are two distinct points in $\mathbb R^m$, the line through $a, b$ can be parameterized by the $l(t) = a + t(b-a)$. For $t=0$ you get $l(0) = a$, then you go from $a$ in direction $b-a$ and for $t=1$ you reach $l(1) = b$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry) "As a vector equation". Lee's approach is slightly different. He compares two vectors on the line and gets the same result - but it seems that he doesn't write it down **explicitly**.

Comment: Ah so it represents a vector? I think that makes sense. What I really have no clue about is your second coordinate function, $1+t({x_{n+1}-1})$ - where is this from and what does it mean? Additionally what does the $i=n+1$ condition signify?

Comment: We have $l_x(t) = (l^1_x(t),\ldots,l^{n+1}(t))$ with real-valued coordinate functions $l^i(t)$. For $i = 1,\ldots,n$ we have $l^i_x(t) = 0 + t(x_i - 0)$ because $N_i = 0$ and for $i = n+1$ we have $l^{n+1}_x(t) = 1 + t(x_{n+1}-1)$ because $N_{n+1} = 1$.

Comment: So for $p(x)$, we consider the case of $N_{n+1}$ because the points will lie on such a hyperplane? Furthermore, I don't understand how you went fro $t_0$ to including the $x_n$ in the numerator, and don't quite get that 'implication' from the first to the second line of working for the inverse, would you please be able to give some hints on that?

Comment: Right, we have $p(x) = l_x(t_0)$ for a suitable $t_0$. But $p(x) \in \mathbb R^n \times \{0\}$ = hyperplane $\xi_{n+1} = 0$ means that the $(n+1)$-st coordinate $l^{n+1}_x(t_0)$ of $l_x(t_0)$ is $0$ which allows to compute $t_0$. The equation $l^{n+1}_x(t_0) = 1 + t_0(x_{n+1} -1)  = 0$ gives us $t_0 = 1/(1-x_{n+1})$. This gives $l^i(t_0) = t_0x_i = x_i/(1-x_{n+1})$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112140/discussion-between-thunderhex-and-paul-frost).

Comment: Im so close to finding this inverse but still don't understand. Solutions I see online and yours too inclue $||a||$, why? What does this norm mean and why is it being squared?

Comment: @ThunderHex You should talk about this with fellow students. It is impossible to give an extensive explanation in written form, this would need hours of time which I cannot spend. You should take the square of the Euclidean norm $\lVert a \rVert^2$ as an abbreviation for $\sum_{i=1}^m a_i^2$. In my first approach it occurs by adding the squares of the components of the vectors on both sides of the equation. Iny my second approach it is due the fact that $S^n$ is the set of points $a \in \mathbb R^{n+1}$ such that $\lVert a  \rVert = 1$ which is equivalent to  $\lVert a  \rVert^2 = 1$.